# InnoSetup and automatic update

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am trying to build installer using InnoSetup. I want automatically upgrade application when update will be available.

Following is algorithm I am trying to implement.

1. When every time app is started, get the latest build info from server file.
2. Compare it with current version of build.
3. If current_version < latest_version, then download the latest build.
4. Quit current app.
5. Install New build.
6. Launch New app.

I checked various examples on internet. Most of examples start with 

`Procedure InitializeWizard`

But what I suspect `InitializeWizard` only checks at start of setup, not at time of launch.

Is that true?

If it is then is there any way in innosetup to check this or do I take care from application code itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Inno Setup does nothing for your application but installing. That's what your application should take care of.

Comment: @TLama In hurry, I paste wrong link. Really sorry for trouble and thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Actually it is possible to create such application in Inno Setup :) Inno is capable of doing all steps you need and I suppose it is much quickier than writing it in C or C++ :)